# Overloading << operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have to make for a project an Album class which uses a Song class. I seem to have problem with overloading the << operator for the Album class.
So this is the album class

---

```
const int Empty=-1
class Album
{
  Song* songs;
  char* name;
  int top=Empty;
public:
  Album ();
  Album (const char*);
  ~Album();
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,Album&);
  void addSong(Song&);
};
```

I'm worried that there might be a mistake with my functions so far but I can't find it.
the program starts but crashes ,any ideas why ? I don't think the problem is in **songs[top]=p**, because i have redefined the assignment operator for the Song class.

---

```
void Album::addSong(Song& p)
{
  ++top;
  songs[top]=p;

}
Album::~Album()
{
  delete[] name;
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Album &p)
{
  os<<"Album name:"<<p.name<<std::endl;
  os<<"Songs in the album:"<<std::endl;
  for(int i=0;i<=p.top;i++)
  std::cout<<p.songs[i];
  return os;
}
Album::Album()
{
  top=Empty;
  name=new char [1];
  name[0]='\0';
}
Album::Album(const char*p)
{
  delete [] name;
  int len1=strlen(p);
  name=new char [len1+1];
  strcpy(name,p);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem: Shouldn't the signature be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,const Album&);` ??

Comment: You should return the same object "os" in overloaded method.

Comment: This is not a big issue, but in `operator<<` you should also use `os<<p.songs[i]` instead of `std::cout<<p.songs[i]`

Comment: Yes. But that i minor problem.Thanks anyway i didn't notice :)

Comment: Moreover, in `Album()` you should set `songs=new Song[MAX_SONGS]` or sth like this

Comment: You say you have redefined the assignment operator for `Song`, perhaps you could show it?

Comment: You should allocate memory for songs member variable in constructor.

Comment: It's probably related to your pointer juggling. Is there any particular reason why you didn't just use `std::string name;` and `std::vector<Song> songs;`? One particular glaring omission is your violation of the rule of three, since it can easily lead to double deletion.

Comment: Well I haven't studied vector yet that why :)

Comment: You probably want addSong to use a `const` reference. Still, why not use use `operator+=` there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overloaded operator is a little broken (as the comments pointed out) but is unlikely to crash your program. There are many problems with this code that will crash it.

To start with, `songs` is not initialized, which means that your `songs[top]=p;` are actually storing the value of p to somewhere in the memory pointed to by stack garbage. That will likely crash your code. You are also not actually allocating storage space to store the `songs` you added. Note that even if you initially allocated space to store one `Song`, you can't just increment `top` and store the next `Song`; your `addSong` will have to dynamically grow the allocated memory. Now, if you have a cap on the number of Songs an album can store, you can use the `songs=new Song[MAX_SONGS]` approach suggested (and make addSong fail if the album hit its max capacity), but it's far better to use `vector`s and `string`s instead of pointers and raw `new`s and `delete`s if possible, and leave the memory management headache to the standard library. (You also didn't provide copy constructors and overloaded assignment operators; you would need both when your class does this sort of memory allocation, to prevent memory leaks and double deletion.)

Note that your constructor that takes a string is also broken; you haven't allocated any memory in `name` at that point so there's nothing to delete.

---

Edit: To elaborate on my comment below, if you have to be able to handle arbitrary numbers of songs and you have to use new and delete, then your `addSong` will have to do something like this (pseudocode):

```
void Album::addSong(Song& p)
{
  new_size = size + 1;
  new_songs = new Songs[new_size];
  for( i = 0; i < size; i++)
     new_songs[i] = songs[i];
  new_songs[size] = p;
  delete [] songs;
  songs = new_songs;
  size = new_size;
}
```

Your destructor will need to `delete [] songs;`. Your constructor should set size to 0 and songs to the null pointer (it's legal to use delete on the null pointer; it has no effect).

You should also overload the assignment operator (which should first delete your own name and songs, allocate enough memory to hold the other album's name and songs, and copy them over) and the copy constructor (which should allocate enough memory to hold the other album's name and songs and then copy them over).

Comment: Thanks for the big answer, but the problem is that we havent studied vector, and in the project it's said the we should use char, new, delete and the number of songs in album isn't limited :(

Comment: Then your `addSong` will actually have to dynamically grow an array manually, which is pretty painful (you'd probably have to `new` an array with a larger size, copy over all the `Song`s from the old array, and then `delete` the old array). It might also be possible touse a linked list for storing the songs, which would make `addSong` a bit easier to write but your destructor and operator << a bit more complicated. Did you do linked lists in class?

Comment: Yes we have , but I have decided to work with vector, screw the system :D. Any info on how to do it with vector ?

Comment: Declare `songs` as `std::vector<Song> songs;` and the body of the `addSong` function becomes simply `songs.push_back(p);`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want:

```
delete [] name;
```

in your constructor, and want:

```
return os;
```

at the end of `operator<<()`.

Also `Songs` isn't used.

Comment: Oops, i forgot it good think I have it for the Song overloading of <<.
PS: It didn't help:(

Answer (score 2):

One source of crashes:

```
Album::Album(const char*p)
{
    delete [] name;   // <--- right here
```

This will take uninitialized memory and apply delete it (it is essentially UB).

Edit (as others have pointed out): songs needs to be initialized (similar to name) before you place stuff into it.

More, to avoid a memory leak, also `delete[] songs` in `Album::~Album`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to allocate memory for songs in the constructors .

Comment: @user3144334, try like this: `songs = new Song[100];` -- this should allocate space for 100 songs.

Comment: That would work, but unfortunately the storing capacity of songs for album should not be limited

Comment: @user3144334, then use a std::vector<Song> instead.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any space for `songs`.